# Does there exists a quadratic extension $L$ of $K$, in which $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$ ramifies in $L/K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $K$ be a number field.

For arbitrarily fixed positive integer $n$, fix $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$ be a  prime elements of ring of integers of $K$.

> Does there exists a quadratic extension $L$ of $K$, in which
> $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$ ramifies in $L/K$ ?

My try: From **Dedekind's Discriminant theorem**, we need to find $L/K$: quadratic such that all $p_i$ divides relative discriminant $\Delta_{L/K}$.

In the case $K=\Bbb{Q}$, Let $D=p_1p_2\cdots p_n$, then, $\Delta_{L/K}$ is $D$ or $4D$, thus $L=K(D)$ is enough in this case.

But in the case $K$ is not $\Bbb{Q}$, I'm stucking with how to find $L/K$: quadratic such that all $p_i$ divides $\Delta(L/K)$ because in this case, $\Delta{L/K}$ is not just $p_1・・・p_n$. **I'm stucking with calculating $\Delta(L/K)$**.

If there are any book or pdf dealing with this proposition, I would also welcome any references. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $\Delta(L/K)$ in your situation ? I'm stucking to calculate  $\Delta(L/K)$  is unlike the case of $K=\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @user297024 I understand. $\Delta_{L/K}$ is a product of local one, $\Delta_{L/K},{p_i}$ and this local one is ${p_i}^{ord_{p_i}(\Delta(L/K)(1,α))}$. $\Delta(L/K)(1,α)=4α$. Thus, if I could find your $α$ as you shown, we are done.

Comment: Take $L = K(\sqrt{p_1 \cdots p_n})$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Is it enough ? In the case, $\Delta{L/K}$ is not precisely $p_1・・・p_n$, but it is enough ?

Comment: "precisely" wasn't part of the question.

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer  In the case $L=K(\sqrt{p_1p_2・・・p_n})$, can you tell me what is $\Delta(L/K)$ ?

Comment: It is the product $p_1 \cdots p_n$ times even powers of prime ideals above $2$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer　Sorry, I'm not familiar with the discriminant of a quadratic extension over a general number field. How did you calculate it? (Did you use a formula similar to the one for $\Bbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: If a prime element $p$ in a number field $K$ divides $a$ to an odd power, then $p$ is ramified in $K(\sqrt{a})$ and therefore divides the relative discriminant. You will find the theory of ramification in Kummer extensions in Hecke's book on algebraic numbers.